# binary tree issue: unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python

I am trying to create a binary tree. I am testing what I have with the test code at the bottom but I receive the error message "elif var < here._variable:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()" any insight would be great

```
class vartree:

    class Node:

        __slots__= "_left", "_value", "_variable", "_right"
        def __init__ (self, l, var,val,r):
             self._left = l
             self._variable = var
             self._value = val
             self._right = r

    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None

    def _search (self, here, var):
        if  here is None:
            return self.Node(None, var, '0', None)

        elif var < here._variable:
            return self._search(here._left, var)

        elif var > here._variable:
            return self._search(here._right, var)

        else:
            return here._value

    def _insert(self, here, var, val):
        if here is None:
            return self.Node(None, val, var, None)

        elif var < here._variable:
            return self.Node(self._insert(here._left, var, val), here._value, here._variable, here._right)

        elif var > here._variable:
            return self.Node(here._left , here._value, here._variable, self._insert(here._right, var, val))

        else:
            return var

    def assign(self, var, val):
        self._root = self._insert(self._root, var, val)
        #self._insert(self._root, var, val)

    def lookup(self, var):
        return self._search(self._root, var)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    T = vartree()
    T.assign("x",9)
    T.lookup("x")
```

Comment: Please show us the entire traceback for the error message.

Comment: Seems to have returned a string here `Node(None, var, '0', None)`. Maybe

Comment: @RoryDaulton   Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 52, in <module>
    T.lookup("x")
  line 46, in lookup
    return self._search(self._root, var)
   line 19, in _search
    elif var < here._variable:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Comment: @cricket_007 I believe you are referring to the '0' which is what I thought but when I correct that to just 0 i manage to get the same error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the formatted traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that one is an integer and the other a string at the line at which error occurs. After analyzing your code, i think i know why this is happening. Do this:

In your _insert() function, 
change this line:

```
  return self.Node(None, val, var, None)
```

to this:

```
return self.Node(None, var, val, None)
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: AHHH just a silly error but thank you so much!! I would have never noticed that

Comment: Glad to help :)